# JPA - how to model entities for this XML document

Tags: xml, jpa, entity

I have some experience writing JPA entities (using the JPA annotations etc.).
I'm looking for a clever way to store the following XML document using JPA, i.e. how to describe the car entities.

```
<and>
   <car>
      <id> 111 </id>
      <model> Ford Mustang </model>
   </car>
   <or>
      <car>
        <id> 222 </id>
        <model> Pontiac Catalina </model>
      </car>
      <car>
        <id> 333 </id>
        <model> Ford Firebird</model>
      </car>
    </or>
    <car>
        <id> 444 </id>
        <model> Chevrolet Impala </model>
    </car>
</and>
```

Any hints?

Comment: What about the <and>/<or>? what is this?

Comment: Basically, the `<and>` and `<or>` represent kind of boolean relationship between these car entities. Thats basically whats my question is about, i.e. how to store these information within the car entities or how to store these relationships seperately...

Comment: How an "or" car relate with other? is there any material with this kind of approach that I may look? If you want just to persist a car, you could use the Car tags, but with those "or" and  "and" that will be harder.

Comment: in the sample scenario you can think of a car as kind of "boolen condition" and my question is how to persist the individual conditions (i.e. cars) as well as the boolean relationship between the individual conditions. The purpose is to have access to the individual conditions (i.e. cars) as well as to the whole boolean expression later on. I hope explanation that was a bit more clear...

Answer (score 0):

I would try to model car entities and boolean relationships with use of [Specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) pattern and JPA inheritance. Single inheritance seems to be the best option here as the entity model is stored as a single database table and offers good performance for polymorphic queries (SQL does not require joins).